# how to code a factorial

Tags: java, factorial

my question is not so much about code as it is the logic behind writing a factorial program. I am currently taking a MOOC at the University of Helsinki and I have become stuck on this exercise. As the course moves on to new exercises the instructions have become more and more vague. I realize this probably isn't the place to ask this question and if you must tag it or remove it, I do understand. I am trying to learn this on my own as I do not have the time or money to actually attend a university. This course has no time constraint and I wont be receiving a certificate of achievement for it, I simply want the knowledge.

these are the instructions given for the exercise

Create a program that calculates the factorial of the number n. The factorial n! is calculated using the formula 1*2*3*...*n. For example 4! = 1*2*3*4 = 24. Additionally, it is defined that 0! = 1.

```
    // i don't understand the example that 4!= 1*2*3*4 = 24 
    // or how 0! = 1 pertains to multiplying numbers in succession to find the
    // factorial of the user input number.
    // i understand that 0! = 1 simply delclares that 0 is not equal to 1 
    // and 4 is not equal to 24, however if the 4! = portion of this statement
    // is in reference to the user input number 4 that statement would not be
    // true as 1*2*3*4 does equal 24 and 4 would be the number of executions
    // of the block execution of the loop required to write the factorial 
    // program.

   // EDIT: okay so according to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial
   // i am wrong about what is being done here as they are not declaring 
   // that 4 not equals 24 but yet that 4! is a way of correlating the non
   // negative numbers up to 4, but given that math is not my strong suit 
   // it is even more confusing to me as to what i should be doing.
```

Example outputs:

Type a number: 3
Factorial is 6

Type a number: 10
Factorial is 3628800

my current code attempt is as follows

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.println("Type a number:");
    int userIn = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int factorial = 1;
    int extra = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    while (factorial <= userIn) {
        factorial++;
        sum = factorial + userIn + extra;
        }
    System.out.println("The factorial is:"+sum);
    }
}
```

I do not understand what it is that i am missing, i know from research that in the real world you would not code this as there are libraries you can download to perform the factorial function that are much more efficient than what i could code, but i don't want to simply skip this exercise with the knowledge that someone else has already coded and created a library to make our lives easier, i want to learn everything that this course has to offer. if i have made a simple error i don't mind an offered code correction, however i want to understand what makes the factorial operation tick so to speak, not just be given the answer so i can move on.

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do here is understand exactly what the factorial operator does. Once you get that, the code should come relatively easily. The Wikipedia article lays it out *really* clearly. What about the factorial confuses you?

Comment: The concept of `4!` is just a compact way of writing `4*3*2*1`. That's it. The factorial of any integer is just itself multiplied by each integer smaller than it. So `5` = `5*4*3*2*1` and similarly, `6!` = `6 * 5!`

Comment: By definition: `n! = n*(n-1)!; 1! = 1!* (1-1)! => 1! == 0!` So you should consider the boundary constraints => factorial(0) == factorial(1) = 1. That is the trick ;). Then if (n > 1) ? factorial(n-1) *n, else return 1;

Comment: i guess its just really that this is the first exercise that uses it and the mathematical formula's that are depicted on the wiki might as well be in Japanese to me, i am not a math major and the highest level of math i ever completed was algebra, and that was literally over 15 years ago for me, i don't understand the formulas or the symbols used in them to come to the answer.

Comment: You are confusing the java "not equals" operator `!=` with the mathematical "factorial" operator `!`. The question uses the factorial operator. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) to explain the concept of a factorial.

Comment: @user3295607 You don't need to be a math major; this is an operation that you should be able to pick up easily. Look at @Kon's explanation; it lays things out pretty well. You can think of `!` just like any other math operator like `+` or `-`. It does something to the number it operates on, and that's the definition. While the Wikipedia definition does go a bit into more formal math, really the first formula there should do it for you.

Comment: you are right, if you see the EDIT i wrote i did figure out that it wasn't declaring not equals but that it was performing some type of operation with the 4! i guess i just don't understand the concept of it really

Comment: @user3295607 If this helps, The factorial's just a shortcut for repeated multiplication on all positive integers less than or equal to the number you operate on. So "4 factorial" is equivalent to `4!`, which is equivalent to `4 * 3 * 2 * 1`. And "5 factorial" is equivalent to `5!`, which is equivalent to `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`. See a pattern?

Comment: okay i think i may understand it a little better now, which means i need to remove some code mainly the factorial++ line and a few others

Comment: @user3295607 You were on the right track with the loop though. Keep that.

Comment: so basically the factorial is the multiplication equivalent of the numbers++ operation? is this correct

Comment: @user3295607 The definition Arnaldo gave you should be helpful: `n! = n*(n - 1)!`. That means for instance, you can find 3!, since it is `3*2!` and 2! is just `2*1!`, so 3! = `3*2*1`, but you can compute it as `3*2!`. That means you can reuse your function to compute factorials when computing them.

Comment: @user3295607 if you wanted to compute `factorial(12)` you might just do something like `return 12*factorial(11);`.

Comment: @user3295607 You also know that `factorial(0)` is 1, so your function should return 1 in that case instead of `0*factorial(-1)`.

Comment: thanks for you comments everyone, i will go back and rework my code from the beginning, i think with all of your examples and explanations that i can piece it together. i feel like i understand what is going on enough now eventually figure it out. @ djechlin  i am trying to actually learn this stuff and i'm not afraid to ask for help when i need it, failing to ask for help is how you fail to learn, and as to the useable code, my code was based on the things we have covered in the course was i supposed to pull the right answer out of my backside and leave you alone.

Comment: is the n! declaration required for this to work, i have tried adding the userIn! = sum; and i get a not a statement error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one if you don't want to use an external function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Type a number:");
   int userIn = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
   int factorial = 1;
   int i= userin;
   while (userin >= 1) {
    factorial *= userIn;
    userin--;
   }
  System.out.println("The factorial is:"+factorial);
 }
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for but can i ask why the ! is not declared in the solution?

Comment: You can declare an ! symbol while you are printing a static string, but You can't make operation with exclamation mark, This can only be used for representing purpose. (I gave this comment according to your questions scenario else ! is a useful operator in programming (We mostly use this one as for Not (bit oprator).

Answer (score 2):

The factorial of a non-negative integer n, denoted by n!, is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n. Eg:- 4!=1*2*3*4 . 0!=1 states that factorial of 0 is 1 and not that 0 is not equal to 1. The value of 0! is 1, according to the convention for an empty product. An empty product, or nullary product, is the result of multiplying no factors. It is by convention equal to the multiplicative identity 1 , just as the empty sum—the result of adding no numbers—is by convention zero (Like the sum of first 0 natural numbers would we 0), the additive identity.
For more on empty products read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

For the programming part, there are basically two approaches to a factorial program:-

1. Using a for loop (No recursion)

   ```
    int factorial ( int input )
    {
       int x, fact = 1;
        for ( x = input; x > 1; x--) // iterating from n -> n-1 -> n-2 ... 1
         {
            fact *= x;              // multiplying each number into the fact variable to get the factorial
          }
         return fact;
     }
   ```
2. Recursive approach -The function calls itself ( Note- avoid using this approach in actual programming as it may be highly resource consuming and bug prone, As pointed out by "Edwin Buck" in the comments)

   ```
    public int Factorial(int n)
      {
       if (n == 0) 
            {
           return 1; //Base condition - If factorial reaches 0 return 1 and end recursion
             }
       else
               {
           return n * Factorial(n-1); // For factorial of n, function returns n * Factorial(n-1) i.e recursively calling  the factorial function with one less value in the parameter untill 0 is reached (upon which base condtiion will be evaluated)
                }
        }
   ```

Comment: Don't teach recursion for factorial.  It is useful when learning recursion to have a toy problem like factorial be presented, but when calculating factorials, it's a horrible waste of resources (and source of bugs).  It's akin to teaching bubble sort when learning about sorting, unfortunately like the often used bubble sort examples, people mostly remember the first thing they were presented with (no matter how much better every other option is).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, edited the description for recursive approach. Thats true, recursive approach for calculating factorials (especially for large numbers) is extremely resource consuming. I myself would never use this approach if at all coding a factorial program is required. But just gave the approach for information purpose. And yes I remenber the recursive approach just because it was presented in college :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
  sum = factorial + userIn + extra;
```

where you "calculate" your factorial from the latest `factorial++` value in the loop.

You can't calculate factorials from sums in this manner.  Factorials are products of all the integers between 1 and the "factorial" number, so

```
  1! = 1
  2! = 1 * 2
  3! = 1 * 2 * 3
  4! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4
```

If you start off calculating your factorial wrong, then the other parts of the problem don't matter much, they will be wrong by extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Factorial example (ie 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)
function factorial($n) {

    if ($n == 1) return 1;
    return $n * factorial($n-1);

}

echo factorial(5); // Outputs 120
// Nested Array Summing Example
$example = array(1, 2, array(10,20,30), 4);

function sum_array($array) {

    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if(is_array($element)) {
            $total += sum_array($element);
        } else {
            $total += $element;
        }
    }
    return $total;

}
echo sum_array($example); // Outputs 67
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to mine, and it was actually a school assignment.
Though question is answered, i will contribute my solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 1;
    int factorial = 1;

    System.out.println("Give number: ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    while (i <= number) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
        i++;   
    }
    System.out.println("Answer is " + factorial);
}
```