# Any Suggestions for Improving my Code on (Negative) Factorial (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, recursion, refactoring, factorial

I was doing a basic problem on coding a factorial **n!**:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
 return undefined;
  } else if (num === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return num * factorialize(num - 1);
  }
}
```

The site I'm learning from accepted this solution, but they're only testing for nonnegative integers, i.e for **n ≥ 0**, not negative integers.

I got curious on how to compute a negative factorial **(-n)!**. Many pages say it's undefined, but I found two saying it could be defined.

- [Link 1](http://aayush1996.blogspot.com/2013/03/factorial-of-negative-numbers.html)
- [Link 2](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-19/NNTDM-19-2-30_42.pdf)

The gist I got is that:

**|n!| = |(-n)!|**

Their absolute values are the same but the negative factorials change signs.

Examples:

**4! = (-4)! = 24**

**5! = 120** but **(-5)! = -120**

The formula that I gathered from the two linked pages is:

**(-n)! =  |n|! * (-1)^n**

And this reflects my code. From test cases, I think I've nailed it. I just want to ask if there's a better way of coding it. Someone from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692893/how-to-code-a-factorial)
remarked that using recursion is memory-inefficient.

```
function factorialize(num) {
 if (num === 0) {
   return 1;
  } else if (num > 0) {
     return num * factorialize(num - 1);
  } else {
     return Math.pow(-1, num) * Math.abs(num) * factorialize(Math.abs(num) - 1);  
    }
  }

// test cases below
    console.log(factorialize(-1)); // -1
    console.log(factorialize(1)); // 1
    console.log(factorialize(0)); // 1
    console.log(factorialize(-2)); // 2
    console.log(factorialize(2)); // 2
    console.log(factorialize(-3)); // -6
    console.log(factorialize(3)); // 6
    console.log(factorialize(-4)); // 24
    console.log(factorialize(4)); // 24
    console.log(factorialize(-5)); // -120
    console.log(factorialize(5)); // 120
```

Comment: I think your question is more on-topic to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO

Comment: @ hindmost, thanks for the tip

Comment: If you decide to post it there, note that your question could use some work. I had to read your question 3 times before it became obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: [Cross-posted with CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115626/52915)

Comment: The standard factorial function is only defined for positive integers. It is often useful and convenient to define 0! = 1. Beyond that, it can be extended in a number of ways. The question is why should it be extended and what does the function represent for negative inputs? The most common extension is probably the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function, which is defined for all complex numbers, but NOT negative integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this using iteration (normally everything that can be done recursively can also be done iteratively). There is also no need to raise -1 to the power of your number. It would be much more efficient, if your just checked if it was odd or even.

```
function factorialize(n){
  var absNum = Math.abs(n);
  var i = 1;
  var factorial = 1;
  while(i <= absNum){
    factorial *= i;
    i += 1;
  }
  if(absNum % 2 === 1 && n < 0){
    return -factorial
  }
  return factorial;
}
```

Comment: except for the missing semicolon, this is a great idea, mate!